# No. VS Not? He had a pen not a pencil

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, negation

I know that we use **not** to negate a verb and we use **no** to negate a noun!

> - he had no pencil

Why do we use **not** in this sentence?

> - He had a pen **not** a pencil

Why don’t we use “no” since no is used to negate or exclude noun?

> - He had a pen **no** pencil.

..............
Is there any grammatical explanation for this?

Answer (score 1):

The second example is a shortened version of a parallel construction:

> 2a. He had a pen not a pencil.
>
> 2b. He had a pen; he did not have a pencil.

Answer (score 0):

There are several uses of the word **no**. The UK version of the MacMillan dictionary has this definition

> used for saying that there is not even one person or thing

with examples such as

> There was no hospital in the town.

We frequently say

> I have no idea

So I see

> He had no pencil

As being in line with these examples, and as a UK native English speaker, would not have questioned such usage. I must admit now the usage is challenged the phrase does seem a little archaic. However I still believe the formulation is valid. We can see "no" as replacing a count when the count is zero.

> He had 5 pencils.
>   He had 1 pencil.
>   He had no pencil.

I do wonder whether

> He had no pencils

Would be better.

According to [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197798/singular-or-plural-verb-after-no) "no" is not strictly a count, and may be used with singular or plural nouns.

In the second case we are correcting a previous incorrect statement

> He had a pen.
>
> He had a pencil not a pen

we are correcting the subject of **had**; the subject is not **pen** it is **a pen** so we include the full subject we are replacing.